# Not able to encrypt data using pgcrypto

Tags: postgresql, encryption

Please forgives me if am wrong here as I am new to the field of encryption/decryption and trying to encrypt data using pgcrypto.

I have created an Extension in my (PostgreSQL 9.6) PgAdmin4 for pgcrypto.

My SpringBoot domain/model class is as follows:

```
@ColumnTransformer(
              forColumn="first_name", 
              read="pgp_sym_decrypt(first_name, 'mySecretKey')", 
              write="pgp_sym_encrypt(?, 'mySecretKey')")
    private String firstName;
```

I have kept the encryption key in the **application.yml** file. When I try to run my springBoot code it runs perfectly but the data is getting inserted as it is without encryption.

Please helps me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried the same approach for the form having only one field and it worked perfectly but when I tried it for the form with multiple fields it gave me following error message:                                                                
                                                                                                       ERROR: function pgp_sym_encrypt(integer, unknown) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts